# react js render differnet component based on button click

Tags: reactjs

so i have this logic where user click a button then based on the clicked button different component get rendered I was wondering if there is a better method to implement this logic

```
function Test(props) {

    const [component, setComponent] = useState("createPatient")
    const [rendered, setRendered] = useState()

    function clickHandler(component) {
        switch (component) {
            case "createPatient":
                setRendered(<PatientForm/>)
                break
            case "findPatient":
                setRendered(<FindPatient/>)
                break
            case "patientsList":
                setRendered(<PatientListTable/>)

        }
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("createPatient")}>Create Patient</button>
            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("findPatient")}>Find Patient</button>
            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("patientsList")}>Patients List</button>


            { rendered  }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the other answers here are correct and work well for your use case. I would like to take it a step further and introduce you to **code-splitting**. It is not necessary but you can always try it.

Presently, you are loading all the components you need at once when your `Test` component is loaded. If your imported components in the future get big or complex, the initial rendering can be slowed down.

**Code splitting** allows you to split your code into small chunks which you can then load on demand.

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mahavira-95gln?file=/src/Test.js:0-1034).

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Test() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState(null);

  const LoadComponent = async location => {
    const { default: component } = await import(`./components/${location}`);
    setComponent(component);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Click the button to proceed</h1>
      <button onClick={() => LoadComponent("PatientForm")}>
        Create Patient
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => LoadComponent("FindPatient")}>
        Find Patient
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => LoadComponent("PatientListTable")}>
        Patients List
      </button>
      {component}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

If you are using the latest version of `React`, you can use `React.lazy`. You'll also need to wrap this lazy component with `Suspense`. You can modify the above code like this to load components with `React.lazy`.

```
import React, { useState, Suspense } from "react";

const LoadComponent = location => {
    const Component = React.lazy(() => import(`./components/${location}`));
    setComponent(<Component />);
  };

return <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>{component}</Suspense>
```

*Always think in terms of how you can ship the least amount of JavaScript to the user.*

Answer (score 1):

the other logic available are roughly similar and doesn't make much of a different in the end result, mostly stylistic and vary in readability; here are two alternative ways;

```
function Test(props) {
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const components = [<PatientForm/>, <FindPatient/>, <PatientListTable/>];

return (
  <div>
     <button onClick={() => setIndex(0)}>Patient Form</button>
     <button onClick={() => setIndex(1)}>Find Patient</button>
     <button onClick={() => setIndex(2)}>Patients List</button>
    {components[index]}
  </div>
)
```

or using boolean approach to render components; something like this;

```
function Test(props) {
const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

return (
  <div>
     <button onClick={() => setStep(0)}>Patient Form</button>
     <button onClick={() => setStep(1)}>Find Patient</button>
     <button onClick={() => setStep(2)}>Patients List</button>
     {step == 0 && <PatientForm/>}
     {step == 1 && <FindPatient/>}
     {step == 2 && <PatientListTable/>}
  </div>
)
```

you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

No need to keep components in state, instead you can directly render them using conditionals.

```js
function Test(props) {

    const [component, setComponent] = useState("createPatient")

    function clickHandler(component) {
        switch (component) {
            case "createPatient":
                setComponent('createPatient)
                break
            case "findPatient":
                setComponent('findPatient')
                break
            case "patientsList":
               setComponent('patientsList')

        }
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("createPatient")}>Create Patient</button>
            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("findPatient")}>Find Patient</button>
            <button onClick={() => clickHandler("patientsList")}>Patients List</button>

         {component === 'createPateient' && <PatientForm/>}
         {component === 'findPatient' && <FindPatient/>}
         {component === 'patientsLis' && <PatientListTable/>}
           
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```